# Music library in android

Tags: java, android, media

in objective-c there is a class that bring all Ipod songs to array, and i am looking for something in android that can connect to the music library of the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`MediaStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) or more specifically, [`MediaStore.Audio`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html).